# Does the convergence of $S_n / \sqrt{n}$ in distribution imply $EX_i = 0$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation, central-limit-theorem

Let $X_1, X_2, \cdots$ be i.i.d. and let $S_n = X_1 + \cdots + X_n$. If $S_n / \sqrt{n}$ converges in distribution, then can I conclude that $EX_i = 0$ without assumption $EX_i ^2 < \infty$?

If $EX_i ^2 < \infty$, then it easily follows from the central limit theorem. But in this case I cannot use the central limit theorem.

In fact, according to Exercies 3.4.3 in [Probability Theory and Examples, Durrett], convergence of $S_n / \sqrt{n}$ in distribution implies $EX_i^2 < \infty$ and thus $EX_i = 0$. However I'm trying to solve this exercise by using the sketch of proof given in the book. That is, I assume $EX_i^2 = \infty$ and try to find a contradiction, and I need to derive $EX_i = 0$ from convergence in $S_n / \sqrt{n}$ in distribution.

Comment: Does $S_n / \sqrt{n}$ converging in distribution imply $S_n/n$ converging to $0$ in some sense?

Comment: No. it converges to some limit in distribution.

Answer (score 4):

In the second edition of Durrett's book, it is asked to show that necessary, $X_1$ has a finite second moment.
The idea  given in Durrett's book is to symmetrise and truncate. More explicitely, let $\left(X'_i\right)_{i\geqslant 1}$ be an independent copy of $\left(X_i\right)_{i\geqslant 1}$ and $Y_i:=X_i-X'_i$. Let $A\geqslant 0$ be fixed and let 
$$U_i:=Y_i\mathbb 1\left\{\left\lvert Y_i\right\rvert\leqslant A       \right\}      \mbox{ and } V_i:=Y_i\mathbb 1\left\{\left\lvert Y_i\right\rvert\gt A       \right\}.   $$
Then we have for any $R$, 
$$\mathbb P\left\{\sum_{i= 1}^n Y_i\gt R\sqrt n       \right\} \geqslant 
 \mathbb P\left( \left\{\sum_{i= 1}^n U_i\gt R\sqrt n       \right\}\cap  \sum_{i=1}^nV_i\geqslant 0    \right) \\
=\frac 12\mathbb P\left\{\sum_{i= 1}^n U_i\gt R\sqrt n       \right\}  $$
where the last equality holds by symmetry (denoting $U=\sum_{i= 1}^n U_i$, $R'=R\sqrt n$ and   $V=\sum_{i= 1}^n V_i$, we have $\mathbb P\left( \left\{\left\lvert U\right\rvert\gt R'        \right\}\cap  V\gt  0    \right) =\mathbb P\left(U\gt R'\right)$
). Let us denote by $Z$ the limit of the sequence $\left(n^{-1/2}\sum_{i=1}^nY_i\right)_{n\geqslant 1}$. If $R$ is a continuity point of the cumulative distribution function of $Z$, then we get, by the central limit theorem, 
$$\mathbb P\left(Z\gt R\right)\geqslant \frac 12\mathbb P\left(\mathbb E\left [U_1^2\right]N\gt R\right)=\frac 12\mathbb P\left(\mathbb E\left [Y_1^2\mathbb 1\left\{\left\lvert Y_i\right\rvert\leqslant A       \right\} \right]N\gt R\right) ,$$
where $N$ denotes a random variable following a standard normal distribution.  If $\mathbb E\left[Y_1^2\right]$ is infinite, then we would reach a contradiction by letting $A$ going to infinity. To conclude, it suffices to show that

> if $X$ and $Y$ are two i.i.d. random variables such that $\mathbb E\left [\left(X-Y\right)^2\right]$ is finite, then $\mathbb E\left[X^2\right]$ is finite.

Comment: how do you know the variance of $U_{k}$ is not zero to apply the CLT?

Comment: We do not need this: $n^{1/2}\sum_{i=1}^nU_i\to \lvert U_1\rvert_2 N$, where $N$ is standard normal.

Comment: Never mind, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Your question can be separated into four parts

> Suppose $X_{k}$ and $X_{k'}$ are i.i.d random variables and that $n^{-1/2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}\Rightarrow Z$ for a real-valued random variable $Z$. Then, show that
>
> $(a)$ Show that $Y_{k}=X_{k}-X_{k}'$ satisfies $n^{-1/2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_{k}\Rightarrow Z-Z'$, where $Z$ and $Z'$ are i.i.d.
>
> $(b)$ For $m>0$, let $U_{k}:=Y_{k}\mathbb{1}_{|Y_{k}|\leq m}$ and $V_{k}=Y_{k}\mathbb{1}_{|Y_{k}|>m}$. Show that for every $u<\infty$ and all $n$, we have $$\mathbb{P}\Big(\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_{k}\geq u\sqrt{n}\Big)\geq\mathbb{P}\Big(\sum_{k=1}^{n}U_{k}\geq u\sqrt{n}, \sum_{k=1}^{n}V_{k}\geq 0\Big)\geq\dfrac{1}{2}\mathbb{P}\Big(\sum_{k=1}^{n}U_{k}\geq u\sqrt{n}\Big).$$
>
> $(c)$ Apply Portmanteau Theorem and CLT for the bounded i.i.d $\{U_{k}\}$ to get for any $u,m<\infty$, we have $$\mathbb{P}\Big(Z-Z'\geq u\Big)\geq\dfrac{1}{2}\mathbb{P}\Big(\mathcal{N}(0,1)\geq \dfrac{u}{\sqrt{\mathbb{E}U_{1}^{2}}}\Big),$$ where $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ is a standard normal random variable. Further considering the limit $m\rightarrow\infty$ followed by $u\rightarrow\infty$, deduce that $\mathbb{E}Y_{1}^{2}<\infty$.
>
> (d) Conclude that if $n^{-1/2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}\Rightarrow Z$, then necessarily $\mathbb{E}X_{1}^{2}<\infty$.

*Proof of (a):*

To prove this, we need to recall a lemma that if $X_{n}\Rightarrow X_{\infty}$, $Y_{n}\Rightarrow Y_{\infty}$, and $Y_{n}$ is independent of $X_{n}$ for $1\leq n\leq\infty$, then $X_{n}+Y_{n}\Rightarrow X_{\infty}+Y_{\infty}$.

Indeed, let $\phi_{n}(t)=\mathbb{E}e^{itX_{n}}$ and $\psi_{n}(t)=\mathbb{E}e^{itY_{n}}$. Since $X_{n}\Rightarrow X_{\infty}$ and $Y_{n}\Rightarrow Y_{\infty}$, we have $\psi_{n}(t)\longrightarrow\phi_{\infty}$ and $\psi_{n}(t)\longrightarrow\psi_{\infty}(t)$. But since $X_{n}$ and $Y_{n}$ are independent, then $X_{n}+Y_{n}$ has characteristic function $\phi_{n}(t)\psi_{n}(t)\longrightarrow \phi_{\infty}(t)\psi_{\infty}(t)$. Being a product of characteristic functions, the limit is continuous at $0$ and thus by the continuity theorem (part 2), we can conclude that $X_{n}+Y_{n}\Rightarrow X_{\infty}+Y_{\infty}.$

Another important lemma is that if $Y_{n}\Rightarrow Y_{\infty}$, then $-Y_{n}\Rightarrow -Y_{\infty}$. Indeed, recall that $Y_{n}\Rightarrow Y_{\infty}$ if and only if for every bounded continuous function $f$ we have $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}f(Y_{n})=\mathbb{E}f(Y_{\infty}).$$

Take $f$ a continuous bounded function, and then set $g(x):=f(-x)$, so that $g(Y_{n})=f(-Y_{n})$. Note that $g(x)$ is also bounded continuous, and thus we have $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}g(Y_{n})=\mathbb{E}g(Y_{\infty}),$$ but then it implies that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}f(-Y_{n})=\mathbb{E}f(-Y_{\infty}),$$ which happens if and only if $-Y_{n}\Rightarrow-Y_{\infty}$.

Combine this two lemmas, we have if $X_{n}\Rightarrow X_{\infty}$, $Y_{n}\Rightarrow Y_{\infty}$ and and $Y_{n}$ is independent of $X_{n}$ for $1\leq n\leq\infty$, then we have $$X_{n}-Y_{n}\Rightarrow X_{\infty}-Y_{\infty}.$$

Let us proceed to the proof of this exercise. Set $$S_{n}:=n^{-1/2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}\ \text{and}\ S_{n}':=n^{-1/2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}',$$ such that $$n^{-1/2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_{k}=S_{n}-S_{n}'.$$

Since $\{X_{k}, X_{k}'\}$ have the same distribution, we know that $\{S_{n}, S_{n}'\}$ have the same distribution for each $n$. Thus if (by hypothesis) $S_{n}\Rightarrow Z$, then $S_{n}'$ must converge in distribution to $Z$ or to any other random variable with the same distribution. In particular, we can take a random variable $Z'$ independent of $Z$ with the same distribution, so that $S_{n}'\Rightarrow Z'$.

Thus, we now have $S_{n}\Rightarrow Z:=S_{\infty}$, $S_{n}'\Rightarrow Z':=S_{\infty}'$ with $S_{n}$ and $S_{n}'$ independent for all $1\leq n\leq \infty$. Indeed, for $n$ finite they are independent because $X_{k},X_{k}'$ are independent for all $k$, for $n=\infty$, they are independent since $Z$ and $Z'$ are independent by construction.

Thus, by the lemma we showed above, we have $$n^{-1/2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_{n}=S_{n}-S_{n}'\Rightarrow Z-Z',\ \text{as desired.}$$

---

*Proof of (b)*

For the first inequality, note that $Y_{k}=U_{k}+V_{k}$, so that $$\mathbb{P}\Big(\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_{k}\geq u\sqrt{n}\Big)=\mathbb{P}\Big(\sum_{k=1}^{n}(U_{k}+V_{k})\geq u\sqrt{n}\Big)=\mathbb{P}\Big(\sum_{k=1}^{n}U_{k}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}V_{k}\geq u\sqrt{n}\Big),$$ and note that $$\Big\{\sum_{k=1}^{n}U_{k}\geq u\sqrt{n}, \sum_{k=1}^{n}V_{k}\geq 0\Big\}\subset \Big\{\sum_{k=1}^{n}U_{k}+\sum_{k=1}^{n}V_{k}\geq u\sqrt{n}\Big\},$$ and thus the first inequality follows immediately.

For the second, note that by construction we have $Y_{k}=_{d}-Y_{k}$ for $1\leq k\leq n$. Using this fact, we prove that the vectors $(U_{1}, V_{1}, U_{2}, V_{2},\cdots, U_{n}, V_{n})$ and $(U_{1}, -V_{1}, U_{2}, -V_{2}, \cdots, U_{n}, -V_{n})$ have the same distribution.

Indeed, since the vectors $(U_{k}, V_{k})$, $1\leq k\leq n$ are independent, it suffices to show that $$(U_{1}, V_{1})=_{d}(U_{1}, -V_{1}).$$

To show this, we show the characteristic functions $\Phi_{(U_{1}, -V_{1})}(s,t)=\Phi_{(U_{1}, V_{1})}(s,t)$, as follows: 
\begin{align*}
\Phi_{(U_{1}, -V_{1})}(s,t):=\mathbb{E}[\exp(i(sU_{1}-tV_{1}))]&=\mathbb{E}[\exp(isY_{1})\mathbb{1}_{|Y_{1}|\leq m}]+\mathbb{E}[\exp(-itY_{1})\mathbb{1}_{|Y_{1}|>m}]\\
&=\mathbb{E}[\exp(isY_{1})\mathbb{1}_{|Y_{1}|\leq m}]+\mathbb{E}[\exp(itY_{1})\mathbb{1}_{|Y_{1}|>m}]\\
&=\Phi_{(U_{1}, V_{1})}(s,t),
\end{align*}
where the penultimate equality was using $Y_{k}=_{d}-Y_{k}$.

Therefore, we have 
\begin{align*}
2\mathbb{P}\Big(\sum_{k=1}^{n}U_{k}\geq u\sqrt{n}, \sum_{k=1}^{n}V_{k}\geq 0\Big)&=\mathbb{P}\Big(\sum_{k=1}^{n}U_{k}\geq u\sqrt{n}, \sum_{k=1}^{n}V_{k}\geq 0\Big)+\mathbb{P}\Big(\sum_{k=1}^{n}U_{k}\geq u\sqrt{n}, \sum_{k=1}^{n}V_{k}\leq 0\Big)\\
&=\mathbb{P}\Big(\sum_{k=1}^{n}U_{k}\geq u\sqrt{n}, \sum_{k=1}^{n}V_{k}= 0\Big)+\mathbb{P}\Big(\sum_{k=1}^{n}U_{k}\geq u\sqrt{n}, \sum_{k=1}^{n}V_{k}> 0\Big)\\
&\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ +\mathbb{P}\Big(\sum_{k=1}^{n}U_{k}\geq u\sqrt{n}, \sum_{k=1}^{n}V_{k}\leq 0\Big)\\
&\geq \mathbb{P}\Big(\sum_{k=1}^{n}U_{k}\geq u\sqrt{n}, \sum_{k=1}^{n}V_{k}> 0\Big)+\mathbb{P}\Big(\sum_{k=1}^{n}U_{k}\geq u\sqrt{n}, \sum_{k=1}^{n}V_{k}\leq 0\Big)\\
&=\mathbb{P}\Big(\sum_{k=1}^{n}U_{k}\geq u\sqrt{n}\Big), \ \text{as desired.}
\end{align*}

---

*Proof of (c):*

Firstly we need to note that this exercise is missing the assumption that $X_{k}$ (or $X_{k}'$) is integrable, otherwise part \textbf{(d)} does not make sense, because over a finite measurable space, we have $L_{2}\subset L_{1}$, and thus if we showed that $X_{1}\in L_{2}$, then $X_{1}\in L_{1}$ must hold, otherwise if $X_{1}\notin L_{1}$, then the result $X_{1}\in L_{2}$ would be a contradiction.

Thus, we need to assume $X_{k}, X_{k}'\in L_{1}$.

We firstly apply the i.i.d CLT to $n^{-1/2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}U_{k}$. ($U_{k}$ are i.i.d since $Y_{k}$ are i.i.d)

Firstly, since $X_{k}, X_{k}'$ i.i.d and they are integrable, we have $\mathbb{E}Y_{k}=\mathbb{E}X_{k}-\mathbb{E}X_{k}'=0$, and therefore, $\mathbb{E}U_{k}=0$.

Therefore, $Var(U_{k})=Var(U_{1})=\mathbb{E}U_{1}^{2}=\mathbb{E}Y_{1}^{2}\mathbb{1}_{|Y_{1}|\leq m}\leq m^{2}<\infty.$

Finally, since $U_{k}$ are bounded, as $n\longrightarrow\infty$, we must have $$\dfrac{U_{1}+\cdots+U_{n}}{n}\longrightarrow 0.$$

Therefore, by the CLT for i.i.d random variables, we have $$n^{-1/2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}U_{k}\Rightarrow \mathcal{N}(0,\mathbb{E}U_{1}^{2})=\sqrt{\mathbb{E}U_{1}^{2}}\mathcal{N}(0,1).$$

Recall that normal distribution is continuous and thus for any $u\in\mathbb{R}$ ($u$ is then a continuous point of the distribution function), we have $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{P}\Big(n^{-1/2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}U_{k}\geq u\Big)=\mathbb{P}\Big(\sqrt{\mathbb{E}U_{1}^{2}}\mathcal{N}(0,1)\geq u\Big)=\mathbb{P}\Big(\mathcal{N}(0,1)\geq \dfrac{u}{\sqrt{\mathbb{E}U_{1}^{2}}}\Big)$$

Now, since $n^{-1/2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_{k}\Rightarrow Z-Z'$, by Portmanteau Theorem, for every $u\in\mathbb{R}$, we have $$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{P}\Big(n^{-1/2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_{k}\geq u\Big)\leq\mathbb{P}(Z-Z'\geq u),$$ since $[u,\infty)$ is a closed set.

Recall from part \textbf{(b)} that $$\mathbb{P}\Big(n^{-1/2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}Y_{k}\geq u\Big)\geq\dfrac{1}{2}\mathbb{P}\Big(n^{-1/2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}U_{k}\geq u\Big),$$ then taking $\limsup$ for $n\longrightarrow\infty$ both hand side, and taking above two results into consideration, we have, for any $u\in\mathbb{R}$, that $$\mathbb{P}(Z-Z'\geq u)\geq\dfrac{1}{2}\mathbb{P}\Big(\mathcal{N}(0,1)\geq \dfrac{u}{\sqrt{\mathbb{E}U_{1}^{2}}}\Big),\ \text{as desired.}$$

In particular, the above result holds for any truncation level $m\in\mathbb{R}$.

To conclude, suppose $\mathbb{E}Y_{1}^{2}=\infty$. Then if we take the truncation level $m$ large enough, then $\sqrt{\mathbb{E}U_{1}^{2}}$ is large such that $$\mathbb{P}\Big(\mathcal{N}(0,1)\geq \dfrac{u}{\sqrt{\mathbb{E}U_{1}^{2}}}\Big)\geq\dfrac{2}{5},$$ and thus $$\mathbb{P}(Z-Z'\geq u)\geq\dfrac{1}{2}\mathbb{P}\Big(\mathcal{N}(0,1)\geq \dfrac{u}{\sqrt{\mathbb{E}U_{1}^{2}}}\Big)\geq\dfrac{1}{5}.$$ Since $u$ is arbitrary, this is a contradiction.

---

*Proof of (d):*

By the argument at the beginning of part (c), we need to assume that $\mathbb{E}X_{1}<\infty$ (and thus $\mathbb{E}X_{1}'<\infty$).

Then, it suffices to prove that for $X, Y$ i.i.d, $X, Y\in L_{1}(\mathbb{P})$ are such that $\mathbb{E}(X-Y)^{2}<\infty$, then $\mathbb{E}X^{2}<\infty$. Because if this claim was true, then putting $X=X_{1}$ and $Y=X_{1}'$ so that $Y_{1}=X_{1}-X_{1}'$, we would have $\mathbb{E}Y_{1}^{2}<\infty$, which has been proved in part \textbf{(c)}, implies $\mathbb{E}X_{1}^{2}<\infty$, as desired.

Since $X, Y\in L_{1}(\mathbb{P})$, then the independent of $X$ and $Y$ implies that $XY\in L_{1}(\mathbb{P})$.

Note that $X^{2}+Y^{2}=(X-Y)^{2}+2XY$. By hypothesis, $(X-Y)^{2}\in L_{1}(\mathbb{P})$, and we just showed that $XY\in L_{1}(P)$, since $L_{1}(\mathbb{P})$ is a vector space, we must have $X^{2}+Y^{2}\in L_{1}(\mathbb{P})$.

Finally, $\mathbb{E}(X^{2})=\mathbb{E}(Y^{2})\leq \mathbb{E}(X^{2}+Y^{2})<\infty$, implies that $X^{2}\in L_{1}(\mathbb{P})$, and thus $\mathbb{E}X^{2}<\infty$, as desired.